# I need to get the image source of images inside links only, convert it into a string and add it to the images as ALT

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the image source of images inside links only, convert it into a string and add it to the images as ALT.

The reason is there are a lot of images on the website and it takes a long time to do it manually. As the heroes are generated dynamically, i want to make sure i am updating only the images inside the links as per ADA requirements ("all images inside links should have ALT tags)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a > img").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("alt") == undefined || (alt = "")) {
      var name = $(this).attr('src');
      name.replace(/(\/+\.+\-+)w+?/, "");
      $(this).attr('alt', name);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perhaps if the code you provided showed an example of your HTML as well?

Comment: so what part of it doesn't work?

Comment: This code looks correct except it does not write it as a aria-label attribute.

Comment: Why would you want to put the image src as aria label? Use alt tag to describe the image or you can just hide the image for screen readers

Comment: I need to add the source of the image as an ALT not aria-label.

Comment: The regex is wrong. It doesn't convert the image path into a string. Instead of  "/core/images/beaches.jpg" as ALT it should be "beaches"

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use the `:has`, `:not` and the attribute selectors to retrieve the `a` elements you want to target based on the `img` they contain. From there you can use `attr()` to set the `aria-label` as required. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('a:has(> img[alt=""]), a:has(> img:not([alt]))').attr('aria-label', function() {
    return $(this).children('img').prop('src').replace(/(\/+\.+\-+)w+?/, "");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><img src="/ignore.jpg" alt="leave me alone" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="/foo.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="/bar.jpg" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple modification to your code to set the `aria-label` attribute of the elements seems to accomplish the goal.

Take a look at the below working snippet which correctly adds the `aria-label` to the first and last elements only.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a > img").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("alt") == undefined || $(this).attr("alt") == "") {
      var name = $(this).attr('src');
      name.replace(/(\/+\.+\-+)w+?/, "");
      $(this).attr('aria-label', name);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
<a><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="alt text"></a>
<a><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="other alt text"></a>
<a><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
```

Comment: Looks like the regex is wrong. It does the job but it needs strip the  image path to plain text - no dashes, no file extensions, no slashes.